# Can`t install Ubuntu 14.04, it keeps restarting

Tags: system-installation

I am unable to install Ubuntu.

As soon as I enter the installation process and click the "next" button for installing it just reboots as if the flash drive has stopped working suddenly.

This happens to me every time.

Comment: Can't you get a DVD to burn Ubuntu 14.04 on that DVD? What software did you use to write the USB pendrive and what architecture for Ubuntu did you download (was it the 32bit iso image or the 64bit image). Did you write the USB inside Windows or inside other Linux distro?

Comment: Same thing happened with DVD too...I was using 64bit ISO, using dd command from Linux. I had Linux Manjaro installed..

Comment: It could be some software related issue. If Linux Manjaro is a 32bit distro then that is the cause. You could ask a friend with a 64bit Windows OS to burn the DVD for you or just write the 64bit Ubuntu iso image on USB with UNetbootin. Or you could use Brasero or similar DVD burning software for writing a new DVD.

Comment: I tried unetbootin and live usb creator....... no results. the set up restarts